# Swift UI Вопрос почему не меняется свойство alha в реальном времени?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Есть ползунок
хочу чтобы при изменении значения ползунка менялись свойство alpha в реальном времени.
Я пытался делать в Action ползунка, но почему-то при изменении значения ползунка не меняется alpha точнее она меняться но при обновлении экрана, как зделать так чтобы она менялась без обновления экранна

```
@IBAction func choiceSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    
    switch segment.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            Slider_ui()
        case 1:
            hiden_slider_section()
        case 2:
            hiden_slider_section()
        case 3:
            hiden_slider_section()
        default: break
    }
}
@IBAction func SliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
    common_label.text = String(sliderControl.value)
}

func Slider_ui(){
    sliderControl.isHidden = false
    common_label.isHidden = false
    viewControlIBO.isHidden = false
    
    common_label.text = String(sliderControl.value)
    
    //----- это не работает почему-то
    
    viewControlIBO.alpha = CGFloat(sliderControl.value)
    
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда вызывается функция Slider_ui() ?

Comment: поправил описания вопроса теперь должно быть более понятно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно, из представленного куска кода, но предложу попробовать решить проблему так (добавить вашу строчку изменения alpha):

```
@IBAction func SliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
   common_label.text = String(sliderControl.value)
   viewControlIBO.alpha = CGFloat(sliderControl.value)
}
```

Ваш @IBAction вызывается каждый раз когда сдвигается слайдер и в вашем варианте кода в @IBAction присутствует только строчка изменения текста лэйбла, а альфу вы меняете почему-то в отдельной функции, которая (повторю свой комментарий) непонятно откуда вызывается (и непонятно, вызывается ли вообще и работает ли она вообще вся).

Comment: Моя ошибка, поправил код в описание вопроса

Comment: Все работает когда я тыкаю по ссылкам в segment и тыкаю обратно на слайдер то alpha меняется, но моя цель чтобы alpha изменялась в реальном времени

Comment: Так а строчку то вы добавили, как в этом ответе?

Comment: Точно. Поправил. Работает. 
Cпасибо вам и извините за мою тупость :)
как говорится на ошибках мы учимся

Comment: Да это ерунда )) Только тогда получается нужно эти же строки удалить из функции Slider_ui() как ненужные там.